# Hold onClick of input type=file, do something I want, and then let browsers start a file-dialog?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display a custom warning message when `<input type='file'...>` is clicked, and then let a browser starts a file-selection dialog with clicking 'Confirm' button. This is to make sure users aware of the warning message correctly. Is it possible?

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [warn, setWarn] = React.useState(false);
  const inputRef = React.useRef();

  const handleChange = e => {};

  const handleClick = e => {
    if (!warn) {
      setWarn(true);
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  const handleContinue = e => {
    const event = new Event("input", { bubbles: true });
    inputRef.current.dispatchEvent(event);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {warn ? (
        <div>
          <h1>WARNING MESSAGE...</h1>
          <button onClick={handleContinue}>Confirm</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        ""
      )}
      <label htmlFor="test-input">
        <input
          id="test-input"
          ref={inputRef}
          type="file"
          onChange={handleChange}
          onClick={handleClick}
        />
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When input is clicked, check if click event was triggered by the browser or via a script. [Event.isTrusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) will be true when click event is triggered by the browser, so in this case use [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent file dialog from opening.

Then write the code that does what you want to do and finally call [event.target.click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) to trigger the click event again but this time `Event.isTrusted` will be false, so file dialog will not be prevented from opening.

Keep in mind that code you want to execute, before the file dialog is opened, should be in the `else` block. Otherwise, it will execute two times.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.isTrusted) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    console.log('doing something....');
    console.log('done. Opening file dialog');
  }
  
  e.target.click();
})
```

```html
<input type="file"/>
```

Comment: thank you. your code gives me a hint to solve my problem. I replaced the dispatchEvent to click() and it worked !!

const handleContinue = e => {
    inputRef.current.click();
  };

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the file picker with `input.click()` but that will also change `event.isTrusted` to false since it wasn't triggered manually by a user interaction

```js
picker.onclick = evt => {
  evt.isTrusted && evt.preventDefault(confirm('are you sure?') && evt.target.click())
}
```

```html
<input id="picker" type="file">
```

`